# Can someone explain this weird Rails ActiveSupport::Duration behavior?

Tags: activesupport

I was playing around with durations (and postgres intervals, long story) and I got this.

```
[6] pry(main)> 30.days.days
=> 2592000 days
```

Why wouldn't it just return `30 days` ? Wouldn't that make sense? What am I missing...?

Comment: Volte, did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the implementation of the `days` method [here](https://github.com/janko-m/as-duration/blob/e494cd4b3ee59160ff8366124117c8d8d15727be/lib/as/duration/core_ext/numeric.rb#L17-L20) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb#L42-L48).

```
  def days
    AS::Duration.new(self * 24*60*60, [[:days, self]])
  end
```

So, everytime you call `.days` it will multiply the current value with `24*60*60 = 86400` and then return the value.

So:

```
[61] pry(main)> 30.days
=> 30 days
[62] pry(main)> 30.days.days
=> 2592000 days
[63] pry(main)> 30.days.days.days
=> 223948800000 days
```

So, if you want `30 days`, just use `30.days` which makes sense!

Comment: But if I want to know how many days a certain Duration is, shouldn't I be able to call `.days` on it? I guess I could use .step(1.day).count but that feels less english-y/rails-y

Comment: yes, you should call .days once. Why do you have to call .days multiple times? `.days.days` ? What do you want to accomplish? give an example.

Comment: Think of it less as saying `30.days.days` and more of `duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.days(30)`, and then calling `duration.days` which one might reasonably expect to return how many days are in the duration.